# The default Android NFC reader overrides the reader in my FLUTTER app

Tags: android, flutter, nfc, ndef

I have an application where I am supposed to scan NFC tags and Call different functions depending on the tag result, but every time I scan an NFC on my phone the default Android reader pops up and the app doesnt recognize it, is there a way I can override the default reader and let the application scan the NFC instead?

```
ValueNotifier<dynamic> result = ValueNotifier(null);
   void _tagRead() {
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(
      onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
      result.value = tag.data;
      if(result.value.toString().toLowerCase()=="main " || result.value.toString().toLowerCase()=="it" || result.value.toString().toLowerCase()=="eng"){
       addRecord(result.value.toString());
      }

      else{
       registerAttendance(result.value.toString());    
      }
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
    });

  }
```

Comment: Have you added the permissions required to the Manifest as per the docs?

Comment: @Andrew yes I did, still not working